# JS The downloaded archive throws "the archive is either unknown format or damaged"

Tags: javascript, zip, blob

I keep getting the problem with downloaded zip file. All the time when I click on the archive it throws "Archive is either unknown format or damaged". I think the problem is with the coding (format of the content of the archive). Please help!

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Unloading/' + $("#radioVal:checked").val(),
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'dateTimeTo': $("#dateTimeTo").val(), 'dateTimeFrom': $("#dateTimeFrom").val() },
    beforeSend: function() {$("#divLoading").show();},
    success: function (result) {
        $("#divLoading").hide();
        if (result.length === 0) {
            var message ="Error";
            $("#dialog-message").text(message);
            $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    close: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            var xmlstr, filename, bb;
            filename = "UnloadedLeases.zip";
            bb = new Blob([result], { type: "application/zip" }); // I think somewhere here is a problem with the coding

            var pom = document.createElement('a');
            pom.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
            pom.setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(bb));
            pom.setAttribute("download", filename);
            document.body.appendChild(pom);
            pom.click();
            document.body.removeChild(pom); //removing the element a from the page
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `$.ajax` doesn't let you download binary content out of the box (it will try to decode your binary from UTF-8 and corrupt it). Either use a jQuery plugin (like [jquery.binarytransport.js](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport)) or use a xhr directly (with [`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)).

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Unloading/' + $("#radioVal:checked").val(),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'binary',                       // using jquery.binarytransport.js
    // ...

    success: function (result) {
        // Default response type is blob
        if (result.size === 0) { // instead of length for blobs
            // ...
        } else {
            var bb = result; // already a blob
            // ...
        }
    }
})
```